# Why can this code not return the bpEffect variable with the value 505.5?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, class-constructors

The expected result from the following code should be 505.5, but instead it returns 3.97541e+70. Why is this the case and how can the problem be solved ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Position {
public:
    Position(int s, double p, string n) {
        shares = s;
        price = p;
        name = n;
    }
    double getBpEffect() {
        return bpEffect;
    }
private:
    string name;
    int shares;
    double price;
    double bpEffect = (shares*price) / 2;

};


int main() {
    Position xyz = Position(100, 10.11, "xyz");
    double buyingPower = xyz.getBpEffect();


    cout << buyingPower;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `(shares*price) / 2` happens too early, before `shares` and `price` get initialized. You are doing arithmetic on random garbage, so of course you get garbage out. Initialize `bpEffect` after you've assigned values to `shares` and `price`.

Comment: Igor is correct. You should be putting `(shares*price) / 2` into a method, such as your constructor, not as an initializing statement in your code.

Comment: as said by Igor Tandetnik, you're managing garbage; garbage in imply garbage out; The solution is obvious: `Position(int s, double p, string n): name{n}, shares{s}, price{p}, bpEffect{(shares*price)/2} {}`

Answer (score 2):

`double bpEffect = (shares*price) / 2;` is run *before* the body of your constructor using the undefined values in `shares` and `price`.  You need to calculate `bpEffect` after you have initialized the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

The shown class gets initialized by a mixture of constructor code, and explicit member initialization.

Unless the order in which various bits and pieces of class construction occurs is fully understood, it's quite easy to get things happen in the wrong order.

The best thing to do is to initialize everything in one place, removing all ambiguity:

```
Position(int s, double p, string n)
   : name(n), shares(s), price(p),
     bpEffect((shares*price) / 2)
{
}
```